# jQuery click() event inside another click() event won't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm looking to make a mobile menu which slides out from the right side of the page, displaying the appropriate navigation once it's displayed. Im using the sidr.js plugin to create the sliding transition and all of the navigation displays fine. I have the mobile menu fully functionality on the computer and the thing looks great and functions the way I want it to.

However, when I switch over to the mobile phone and go to the website, the navigation has a major flaw. I placed a button at the top of the navigation area that closes the side navigation when it's clicked. Below is the function that performs this task and on the computer it's fine. The problem is that it won't work in mobile!! Please help, I'm confused why this isn't working.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.btn.btn-default.mobile-btn', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#responsive-menu-button").click();
});
```

You can also view the problem live at http://mgm702.github.io but you must be on a mobile device to notice the issue. Also, I have already tried the `cursor: pointer;` option among others and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for my particular situation. I was using the [Sidr.js Plugin](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) and one of the features is a built in function that closes the menu slider. I attached this to the function I was currently using, and this corrected the issue. The menu then worked with the mobile device touch interface. My final function looks like this

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', 'a.btn.btn-default.mobile-btn', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.sidr('close','sidr-main'); 
});
```

I hope this anwser helps someone in the future dealing with this issue!

Answer (score -1):

Adding `data-role="button"` to your `responsive-menu-button` should do the job.

Comment: that unfortunately didn't work. If you look at the new code on the website, I have added the data-role="button" to the responsive-menu-button and it still won't work on mobile devices.

Comment: Is the closing event the only thing that is not working? have you tested with other events?

Comment: yeah the click event is the only thing not working. I originally had a fadeIn and fadeOut  event set up inside of the function so that the close menu text would disappear when you clicked the button. I thought this was the problem however, so I decided to remove it from the function. Still didn't help though.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right jquery mobile plugin? and have you tried `tap`? http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/

Comment: Yeah I tried `tap`, `trigger("click")`, and I did `bind.on("click",function(){})`. All of them didn't perform the correct event needed.

Comment: Can you add `$(document).ready(function() {` to the beginning of your code?

Comment: Yeah, I just added  `$(document).ready(function() { })` to the code. However, the mobile issue is still present. I think it's stuck on the second click() event handler, I'm just not sure how to get it perform the same task as it does in the browser.

Comment: Try the following instead of `$("#responsive-menu-button").click()` put `$("#responsive-menu-button").prev("a.ui-btn").unbind().click()`

Comment: I tried `$("#responsive-menu-button").prev("a.ui-btn").unbind().click()` instead of `$("#responsive-menu-button").click()`. However, this caused more of an issue and now the menu doesn't work on the computer browser either. I also added an alert to the function in order to test if the event is triggering initially. It seems to make it through the code just fine and the alert is displayed on the mobile browser.

Comment: That' unbinding was just for the mobile version and won't work on computer browser. The reason is because when you create a button, jQM transforms it by hiding the original button ("#responsive-menu-button") and creating a nicely styled anchor tag which is what is actually seen. Is the alert displayed in the mobile version too?

Comment: I figured the unbinding wasn't going to work on the browser, unfortunately it still didn't fix the mobile issue. The alert is displaying on the mobile version as well. Thank you so much for helping me out with this I really appreciate it!!